# Adding bulk slides to SXA Gallery component

Tags: sxa

In our Sitecore structure we have several property types which are buckets and contains properties[image]

Test is a property which takes its gallery data from /Data/Gallery. Since property items are bucketable, it is not ideal to add gallery slides from content editor.
When the property is opened in experience editor, to add 1 slide we need to follow the following steps(long process).

1)Click on the + sign shown in the screenshot below
[image]

2) Select the template and name the gallery image item [image]

3) Add the actual image.

[image]

All these steps make it a long process. If a content author have to add average 10 slides per property, it is very inconvenient for them to follow this process for each slide.

Through content editor- not ideal as we are using buckets.

Through experience editor- it is a long process to add each slide.

Is there any way we can add bulk slides to the SXA Gallery component? What can be the ideal way to achieve this functionality so that it is easy and fast for content authors to add slides to the Gallery?